# External Ids in salesforce

Tags: externalid

multiple records might have the external id. 
I want to Query all the duplicate Records ,I want to know all the Records which is having same external Id

How can I perform this query?

The Answer is:

```
SELECT External__c, count(Id) records FROM MyObject__c
GROUP BY External__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

If you are open to using Apex, you can generate a Set based on the above. If your volume is low enough, you can do it all in one go:

```
Set<String> externalIds = new Set<String>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT External__c FROM MyObject__c
    GROUP BY External__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
]) externalIds.add((String)aggregate.get('External__c'));

List<MyObject__c> duplicates = [
    SELECT Id, External__c FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE External IN :externalIds
];
```

I am Having Large Number of Records,How to Query? then I want to know all records which is having same External Id,Guide Me for the Answer

Comment: why don't you use `SELECT External__c, count(Id) records FROM MyObject__c
GROUP BY External__c HAVING count(External__c ) > 1`

Comment: @TusharSharma No records is Displaying to Me

Comment: @TusharSharma I want to display all the Recordids which have the same external Id for External_c field How

Comment: I may have Different Recordtypes that may be caused the Problem ah? @TusharSharma

Comment: @eric ,@adrian Larson,@tushar sharma i am created the field as set as external Id  and now i am changing the field to set as unique record identifier, i am not able to change,for that i want to query all the duplicate records with different Record id ,How to Query ,The above query displaying count field only,i want all Record ids,which have same external id field

Comment: When you will convert it SF will display record Id in error. You can take help from there.

Comment: @TusharSharma how i will convert into Sf, guide Me for the Answer

Comment: @TusharSharma what are the steps I have to follow to change the Unique field for the Particular field Guide Me for the Answer